# Trying to get Oracle Forms - Jinitiator 1.3.1.22 to work with IE11 on Windows 7

Tags: oracle, windows-7, internet-explorer-11, jinitiator

**Update**

I am considering manually changing the code through Chrome to get the page to use a more up to date Java runtime environment. The code:

```
<embed src="" pluginspage="/forms/jinitiator/us/jinit_download.htm" type="application/x-jinit-applet;version=1.3.1.22" java_codebase="/forms/java" java_code="oracle.forms.engine.Main" java_archive="frmall_jinit.jar" width="100%" height="100%" hspace="0" vspace="0" serverurl="/forms_uatplacementsheet/lservlet?ifcfs=/forms_uatplacementsheet/frmservlet?acceptLanguage=en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6" networkretries="0" serverargs="escapeParams=true module=logon.fmx p_database=DOPSSUP1 p_initial_form=ps_menu.fmx userid=  sso_userid=%20 sso_formsid=formsApp_clntuat1_7E435F00D52D11DA9F7CC7B9618E10F6 sso_subDN= sso_usrDN= debug=no host= port= buffer_records=no debug_messages=no array=no obr=no query_only=no quiet=yes render=no record= tracegroup= log= term=" separateframe="false" splashscreen="" background="" lookandfeel="generic" colorscheme="gray" serverapp="default" logo="" imagebase="DocumentBase" formsmessagelistener="" recordfilename="" endusermonitoringenabled="" endusermonitoringurl="" heartbeat="" disablevalidateclipboard="">
```

Has me slightly baffled, what do I change to make it work with the later version of the JRE?

**End Update**

I have a client using with the following setup:

> 1. Desktop:
>
>    - Windows XP SP3
>    - Jinitiator 1.3.1.22
>    - Internet Explorer 7
> 2. Server:
>
>    - Solaris 10
>    - IAS/OFR 10.1.2.2.0
> 3. Database:
>
>    - Oracle Database 11.1
>    - Oracle Database 10.2

There is an upgrade project underway and it will eventually be brought up to the latest and greatest version of Oracle etc.

The problem is the XP/IE7 combo. There is a Windows 7/IE11 upgrade project underway and the Oracle Forms Apps need to be available on this new desktop setup until the Oracle upgrade has occurred.

Now the kicker, a "tactical solution" has been proposed by a non technical person:

> 1. Install multiple versions of the JInitiator onto the desktop
> 2. Run IE11 in "compatability" mode for IE7
> 3. Oracle form apps will continue to work

The problem is that the JInitiator executable doesn't want to play nice with IE11.

I have been perusing the interweb and praying to the Great Pumpkin to find out if there is some way of finding out if this particular setup is going to work without having a bunch of people running around pulling levers, flicking switches and fiddling with knobs.

Would any of you gentle folk be able to help me?

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved easily using Browsium ION.. Please see [www.browsium.com/ion](http://browsium.com/ion)

ION Can be used to swap out and use Jinitiator 1.3.1.22 instead of the highest version of java installed on the client (say Java JRE 8u121). This can be achieved by using an ION Custom file, this is used to swap the Java dlls to expose the Jinitiator 1.3.1.22 dlls to the application, instead of the highest installed version of Java. We also swap out the Java Jinitiator 1.3 jvm.dll and use the 1.4.2_19 version of jvm.dll

It is also required to amend the security settings in the Deployment.properties file. This can also be achieved using a Browsium ION Custom File.

We have found it is sometime necessary to intercept and change the CLSID of the Java version called in the javascript.

j-init 1.3 CAFECAFE-0013-0001-0022-ABCDEFABCDEF
 Java 8u121 CAFEEFAC-0018-0000-0121-ABCDEFFEDCBA  (if the highest version on the machine is java 8u121)

This can be performed using an ION String Replacement

All of the above can be simply applied using the Browsium ION Configuration Manager. In the example I have tested I also applied a Document mode of 5, as I assume if the site is using J-initiator it was probably written for IE6 or IE5.. :-) Browsium ION can also fix this by changing the Doc mode and the User-Agent String  and all this is achieved on the client with no changes to the Server..

to try out this approach download the Browsium ION Eval software - https://www.browsium.com/ion/eval/

After downloading the software, please ask support for a test configuration file with the settings above to get you started.

I am a Client manager for Browsium.

Comment: Are you in some way connected to this product? In case this is so, please mention it in your answer.

Comment: Yes I'm as support engineer for Browsium

Comment: Please mention it in your answer (edit it), as stated in [How to not be a spammer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"you* must *disclose your affiliation in your answers."* (so not just in a comment)

Comment: Answer edited. Sorry you had to chase me on this. Now complete